# Installing GRUB to first sector of /dev/sdb damages partition table

Tags: grub, embedded

I'm trying to build a linux-based embedded OS using buildroot framework. After compilation I extracted contents of root filesystem on micro SD card. Now I need to install GRUB. I have stage 1 and stage 2 files. trying to write them on first sectors of /dev/sdb (using a memory reader) destroys partition table:

```
dd if=stage1 of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
dd if=stage2 of=/dev/sdb bs=512 seek=1
```

Also installation on a partition (/dev/sdb1) causes damage on it.

How do I install GRUB?

Comment: Assuming 512-bytes sectors, you are writing to both the first and the second sector. I have never seen the need to use `dd` on anything else than the first sector (the MBR). A partition could start at the second sector, so you may damage it.

Answer (score 1):

You're directly overwriting the boot sector / partition table with the `stage1` and `stage2` files, when you use `dd` like that.  Instead, you should use [grub-install](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html) (or the lower-level `grub-mkimage` and `grub-setup` commands, as mentioned in that link).